# Tucking Tzitzis knots in

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tzitzis

It seems that the minhag of a lot of people is to have their Tzitzis strings hanging out while their knots are tucked in. Is there a known source for this minhag?

Comment: Rumor I'd heard was that back when everyone knotted their own, those whose knots weren't as nice were embarrassed. So the custom became that only the strings would be visible.

Comment: Perhaps it’s a compromise between those who say not to wear it out add those who say you must wear it out.